# Unable to launch vega-editor

Tags: node.js, vega, vega-lite

The `vega-editor` allows interactive editing and viewing of rendered `vega` and `vega-lite` visualizations.    https://github.com/vega/vega-editor

I have installed it according to the directions on the `README.md`.  The `npm link` did not work in either `vega` or `vega-lite`: so I manually copied the `.js` into the `vega-editor/vendor` directory:

```
 $pwd
/git/vega-editor/vendor
05:51:58/vendor $ll vega*.js
-rw-r--r--  1 boescst  admin  405255 Apr 30 23:49 vega-lite.js
-rw-r--r--  1 boescst  admin  170943 Apr 30 23:50 vega-lite.min.js
-rw-r--r--  1 boescst  admin  879846 May 14 00:29 vega.js
-rw-r--r--  1 boescst  admin  553130 May 14 00:29 vega-core.js
-rw-r--r--  1 boescst  admin  386015 May 14 00:29 vega.min.js
-rw-r--r--  1 boescst  admin  234204 May 14 00:29 vega-core.min.js
-rw-r--r--  1 boescst  admin   17694 May 14 05:31 vega-embed.min.js
-rw-r--r--  1 boescst  admin   93163 May 14 05:31 vega-embed.js
```

That did fix the `404` issues with the `vega.js` and `vega-lite.js` . The main `index.html` only shows blank page however. Using `view source` we see:

[image]

So what might be missing here to get the editor web page up?

Answer (score 0):

Try the new react based editor at https://github.com/vega/vega-editor/tree/redux. Also, please report issues directly on GitHub as we don't monitor SO regularly for issues.